# Synchronisation between process context and timer function

Tags: c, linux, timer, linux-kernel, spinlock

I want to update a data structure atomically in both process context (in queuecommand function to be specific) and timer function. In process context, should I use `spin_lock_bh` or `spin_lock_irq` or just `spin_lock`?

As per my understanding, we should use `spin_lock_bh` in queuecommand (process context) and just `spin_lock` in timer function. Am I correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, it is about [`timer_list`](https://lwn.net/Articles/735887/) ([bottom half context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14321869/what-context-does-a-linux-kernel-timer-function-runs-in)). Then your assumption is correct: yes, it would be sufficient to use ***`spin_lock_bh` in process context*** and ***`spin_lock` in timer handler*** (`function` of `timer_list`). But this is true only ***if that lock*** (and the corresponding data structure) <strike>is used only in the mentioned contexts</strike> ***is not used it interrupt handler***. If so, you need e.g. `spin_lock_irq`.

Also keep in mind that you shouldn't use sleep-able functions inside `spin_lock*`-`spin_unlock*`.

<sub>There are a lot of examples in Linux kernel sources, e.g.:</sub>

- <sub>[spin_lock](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.13.16/source/drivers/net/wireless/intersil/hostap/hostap_ap.c#L230) in timer + [spin_lock_bh](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.13.16/source/drivers/net/wireless/intersil/hostap/hostap_ap.c#L502) in process context;</sub>
- <sub>[spin_lock](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.13.16/source/drivers/net/ethernet/broadcom/b44.c#L919) in interrupt handler and [spin_lock_irq](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.13.16/source/drivers/net/ethernet/broadcom/b44.c#L606) in timer.</sub>